# "apt-get" breaks when changing mirrors for Focal on the NanoPi R4S

Tags: drivers, apt, updates, apt-mirror

I am using a version of Focal made for the NanoPi R4S with appropriate drivers, which comes with mirrors linking to China.

Not only are these slow because I am in the US, I also do not trust software from the mainland China.

When I use nano to edit the mirrors and change them to a fast mirror in the US, everything breaks, apt-get update, even install curl says there is no install candidate for curl.

Comment: Can you post sources.list ?

Comment: I can't post it here, stack exchange marks my message as spam because it contains like 10 links. How else could I share them?

Comment: Post it in your question. You must format it as a code block in your question so it doesn't get flagged. First, copy and paste it into your question, then highlight the code, and then press CTRL+K and then save your changes.

Comment: tried that too, said "your message looks like spam" :(

Comment: please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1399626/edit) your question include contents of 'sources.list', not as a comments

Comment: It still will not allow me to update it unfortunately.